# Citrix remote desktop not working on new computer

Tags: remote-desktop, citrix, receiver

I got a new computer at work and I need to work remotely using citrix receiver. It works on my old computer. I download a .ica, launch it, and a remote desktop opens where I can work. The old computer had windows 7.

On the new computer, I installed the last version of citrix and tried, but it doesnt work. I dont get any error, it actually seems to work, but needs like 1 minute to detect my mouseclicks, until it finally disconnects. The new computer has windows 10.

I tried to uninstall the lastest version of citrix receiver, and install the same I have on the old computer (4.6) but the same happens.

So, the problem is it works VERY slow (1 minute to detect each click) and then before I even log into the remote machine, it just disconnects.

Im using the same network and citrix receiver version than in my old computer. Any idea if it can be windows 10 related or how can I find out what it is causing it?

Maybe this info can help: Ive noticed a difference when opening the network central. On my old computer (where it works) I see: Terminal Server - Citrix receiver. And at the bottom it says: 1 server 0 remote applications

On the new computer (doesnt work) it says: MAD-BDCOT-PS-02 - Remote Desktop Connection. And at the bottom: 1 server 1 remote application

That's the only difference I see, but Ive done the same in both cases.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Made it work.
After trying many things for 2 days, even installing almost every citrix receiver version, a coworker gave me a file called CitrixOnlinePluginWeb, Instead of CitrixReceiver.

I dont know what it is, and I cant post a link since he gave it to me, but Im sure knowing the name makes it easy to find in google. With this, it worked.

By the way, I think the problem was windows 10, since before knowing this other installable, I tried in several computers, and it always worked on win7 ones and didnt on win10 ones.

Comment: We are facing issue on windows 7 using Citrix receiver version 4.12(latest) however it's working fine on windows 10. On opening.ica file, it's showing "unknown connection error DA_Desktop 1110".  Any idea how to resolve this?? Thanks in advance